# Texturing and baked normal map problems

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-baking, normal-map

hi i have huge problem i don't understand why i see low poly model mesh in render view when i add a baked normal map. Where is this strange black light coming from? I've only added HDR texture and the rest of the models are hidden so it's not a shadow of the other models. I have problems with unpacking and texturing, and constant errors don't help me learn. Moreover, whenever I unpack a low-poly model and bake texture, I always see the seams on the model in render view. I hope that someone can explain me what should I do ;)
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (copy paste the URL it will create)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I can only send you link from google drive and I hope it will be fine.                      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ocp0tQirec53Gcy7NbaKFOa69FtUebh0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: weird because I don't have your problem, have you tried with another Blender version? or another computer? Also maybe try with a 32-bit float picture even though I don't think it's your problem here.... maybe someon will tell...

Comment: I'm confused, I have already tried with a 32-bit float picture and I had the same result. I will try with another blender version, but maybe someone will tell me what's going on in my project.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded new version of blender and it worked. I don't understand why I saw that problem but I'm happy that everything is okay now.

Comment: oh ok cool, maybe there was a problem with baking with one of the last versions